# How to make css change using jQuery find()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**htmlCODE:**

```
<body style="padding: 80px; z-index: -2">
  <div class="reaction" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: blue; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 1">
    <div class="" style="position:absolute; border-radius: 50%; background-color: purple; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 0;"></div>
    <div class="circle" style="position:absolute; border-radius: 50%; background-color: skyblue; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 0"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

**Well working jQueryCODE:**

```
$('.reaction').mousedown(function () {
  $(this).find('div').css('left', '70%');
});
```

This CODE seems to working well, but

**Worse working jQueryCODE:**

```
$('.reaction').mousedown(function () {
  $(this).find('div.circle').css('left', '70%');
});
```

This Worse CODE is also works but it make the size of `div.circle` to `0*0` from `40*40` in elements tap of browser developer tools. (`style="left: 70%;"` seems to be working well)

Why size of `.circle` goes 0 * 0 after `Worse working jQueryCODE`?

Comment: I don't see any errors [in this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/core972/1pu4gs47/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both code are working fine. No worse code. The issue is

`$(this).find('div')`.... It is targeting the both the div inside `.reaction` and thats why both the div getting `left:70%`

`$(this).find('div.circle')`...Its targeting to only div that has circle class.

***Stack Snippet***

```js
$('.reaction').mousedown(function() {
  $(this).find('div').css('left', '70%');
  $(this).find('div.circle').css('left', '30%');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body style="padding: 80px; z-index: -2">
  <div class="reaction" style="border-radius: 50%; background-color: blue; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 1">
    <div class="" style="position:absolute; border-radius: 50%; background-color: purple; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 0;"></div>
    <div class="circle" style="position:absolute; border-radius: 50%; background-color: skyblue; width: 40px; height:40px; z-index: 0"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```